# Regular expressions - remove all non-alpha-numeric characters CRLF problem

Tags: php, regex

First off, if it's not clear from the tag, I'm doing this in PHP - but that probably doesn't matter much.

I have this code:

```
$inputStr = strip_tags($inputStr);
$inputStr = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z\s]/", " ", $inputStr);
```

Which seems to remove all HTML tags and virtually all special and non-alphabetic characters perfectly.  The one problem is, for some reason, it doesn't filter out carraige return/line feeds (just the combination).

If I add this line:

```
$inputStr = preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $inputStr);
```

at the end, however, it works great.  Can someone tell me:

1. Why doesn't the first preg_replace filter out the CR/LFs?
2. What this second preg_repalce is actually doing? I understand the first one for the most part, but hte second one is confusing me - it works but I don't know why.
3. Can I combine them into 1 line somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first regex is removing all characters that are not letters or whitespace. CRLFs are whitespace, so they aren't filtered out.

The second one is replacing whitespace with a space character. Essentially it condenses sequences of whitespace into a single space (due to the quantifier being greedy).

I suggest removing the `\s` from the first regex, see if that works.

Comment: Thanks man.  One day I'll have enough time to read a good regex tutorial and practice, haha.  I think its much needed.  I'll go give it a try and let you know later.

Answer (score 2):

1. You told it to remove everything except letters and whitespace. Newlines are whitespace, so they don't get removed. You could use `\h` instead of `\s` to only exclude *horizontal* whitespace.
2. It simply means "replace every sequence of one or more whitespace characters (`\s+`) with a single space."
3. `preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z]+/", " ", ...)` might do.

Answer (score 1):

1. `\s` matches whitespace such as `\n`.
2. It is replacing all whitespace characters with a space.
3. You could make it one unreadable line, but probably not one regex.